# How to find out where a cookie is set?

Tags: cookies, varnish

I am trying to find out where a cookie is being set.

I am running Varnish cache and want to know where the cookie is being set so I know if I can safely remove it for caching purposes.

The response headers look like this;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
Expires: Mon, 05 Dec 2011 15:11:39 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=7200
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Session: NO
X-Cacheable: YES
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2012 15:29:40 GMT
X-Varnish: 1233768756 1233766580
Age: 1081
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache: HIT
```

There is no cookie present. But when loading the same page in a browser the headers are the same, I get a cache hit and no cookie in the response headers.

But then the cookie is there all of a sudden, so it must be being somewhere. Even if I remove it it reappears. It even appears in Incognito mode in Chrome. But it is not in the header response.

I have been through all the javascript on the site and cannot find anything, is there any other way of setting a cookie?

Thanks.

Comment: If you also give the name of the cookie maybe someone can know of any 3rd party scripts or common sources for that cookie. Facebook, twitter or tracking scripts (for true tracking or from ads) are most often the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Set-Cookie header goes through Varnish at some point, you can use varnishlog to find the request URL:

```
$ varnishlog -b -m 'RxHeader:Set-Cookie.*COOKIENAME'
```

This will give you a full varnishlog listing for the backend requests, including the TxURL to the backend which tells you what the client asked for when it got Set-Cookie back.